# creating regular subgraph through edge deletion

Tags: algorithm, graph, subgraph

**The problem:**
Given a Q-regular undirected graph, I'm looking for an algorithm to identify an N-regular undirected subgraph through edge deletion. N < Q (obviously), and it's important that some degree of randomness can be implemented in the algorithm, since I need to sample the space of N-regular subgraphs.

**What I've tried:**
So far, my best method has been finding a Hamiltonian cycle, and deleting every other edge on the cycle. This nicely creates a (Q-1)-regular subgraph and can in principle be repeated until the desired degree of regularity has been reached, or I inadvertently create a graph with no Hamiltonian cycle. However, this approach is slow (this is my main issue) and it's a bit problematic that it relies on the otherwise completely unnecessary restriction of a Hamiltonian cycle.

**My Question:**
Can anyone suggest an alternative to the Hamiltonian cycle approach, or perhaps simply tell me that the problem is inherently hard and that a faster solution than Hamiltonian cycle detection is unlikely? I realize that I'm flirting with some graph theory concepts here, but I'm afraid that I don't have the expertise to frame it more formally.

Thank you for your time :)

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention that the number of vertices (= L) in the original network is even. I have made this restriction to ensure that a regular graph can be created, since this is impossible if both L and Q are odd, and I wish to have as few restrictions on Q as possible. 
Second, I do indeed wish to retain all vertices (hence I only mentioned edge deletion).

Comment: The approach via Hamiltonian cycles is not necessarily a good one since a) it might be the case that there is no Q-1-regular subgraph that spans all original vertices while there might be other Q-1-regular subgraphs and b) finding a Hamiltonian cycle is NP-hard even for Q-regular graphs [with Q ≥ 3](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/1656/8871).

Comment: Also, the Hamiltonian cycle approach requires the number of vertices to be even.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you want the subgraph to contain all original vertices? I'm realizing just now that you could mean that.

Comment: You're trying repeatedly to find a 1-factor and remove it. This won't work in general; see, e.g., http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520203/k-regular-simple-graph-without-1-factor . If you can find one by some means and want to randomize it, then the Markov chain approach that I suggested on your previous question still applies (though I don't know what the convergence rate will look like).

Comment: @G.Bach: I'm aware that the Hamiltonian cycle approach might be suboptimal, that's why I came here :) I'm just not very experienced with graph theory, so I wasn't able to come up with anything better. But thanks for your comments :)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat would the randomization technique still create a subgraph of the original Q-regular graph? I was under the impression that it is uniformly distributed over all graphs with the same regularity?

Comment: You'd reject the changes that would insert an edge not in the supergraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative approach would be to construct a maximum matching (e.g. using [Edmond's Blossom algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm)).

This constructs a set of edges such that each vertex is connected to at most one edge.

This may be more efficient than finding a Hamiltonian path and more likely to work (e.g. for disconnected graphs).

Deleting the edges in the maximum matching will result in a Q-1 regular graph if and only if every vertex is connected to exactly one edge in the matching.  (It is impossible for a vertex to be connected to more than one edge, but it may be possible for some vertices to be connected to 0 edges.  However, I believe this will only happen if it is impossible to have a Q-1 regular subgraph.)

To make it randomized you could consider using a [weighted matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm#Weighted_matching) and use random weights.

Comment: I'm not sure Kaare wants an algorithm that only works on marriage graphs (i.e. graphs fulfilling the Hall condition). You could of course iterate over all induced subgraphs and check which of them is a marriage graph, but obviously that would take exponential time.

Comment: Agrred, although it should work in every case his current approach works with, plus some additional cases (and be faster which was his main concern).  I believe it will only fail if it is actually impossible to make any Q-1 regular graph at all from the original graph.

Comment: It will work faster than the Hamiltonian cycle approach he mentioned, and it will give more cases, true. I just realized that Kaare did not specify explicitly whether the subgraph is supposed to contain all original vertices, so this approach actually is correct in case that keeping all vertices is what he wants.

Comment: @G.Bach Good point - I hadn't considered that he might want a subgraph with some vertices omitted, I guess we will have to wait for clarification from Kaare.

Answer (score 3):

In [this article](http://www.rairo-ro.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=8223925), the authors provide a way to transform a special `Q-regular` graph to a  `Q-1 - regular` one in `O(n^3)`, which implies your problem is solvable in `O(n^4)` for some special cases. You might want to take a look at the article and see if it's any help for you.

Comment: Note that the abstract of the paper says that the algorithm only works for a specific family of Q-regular graphs and that in the graphs not belonging to that family, there is another family of Q-regular graphs for which no Q-1-regular subgraphs exist.

Comment: Thank you, you're right, I misunderstood the abstract. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs to me that a variation of the answer by Peter de Rivaz is to find N consecutive complete matchings from the original graph, and then build the network as the join of these N matchings. If N < Q-N, this is faster than creation-by-pruning, and has the advantage that it also works if the original graph was not itself regular.